How do I detect when a video played in a webview has ended in react native?
This is the code where I render a webview to play a video. I am trying to call a function 'EndVideo' when the video ends, but it is not being called. What am I doing wrong here?
return (
        <View style={{height: 200,width:common.width,zIndex:1}}>
          <WebView nativeConfig={{props: {webContentsDebuggingEnabled: true}}}
                   style={{height: 200,width:common.width}}
                   useWebKit={true}
                   mixedContentMode='always'
                   ref={(webView) => webRef = webView}
                   javaScriptEnabled={true}
                   injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
                   scalesPageToFit={true}
                   onMessage={this.onMessage.bind(this)}
                   source={{html: `<head> <meta content="width=width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport"></head><video id="video1" width="${common.width-15}" height="${200}" playsinline controls ended = {this.EndVideo} src="${videoUri}" ></video>`}}
                   onLoadEnd={that.onLoadEnd}
                   onLoadStart={that.onLoadStart}
                   allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
          />
        </View>
      )

I have tried different getting the elementById and doing .onEnded. Etc.
